# Create Left / Right Transition Effect

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide, slidetoggle

I am trying to create a slide transition effect like the one posted in the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZTiJmclaRc.

When the button is clicked the current div#1 will be sliding out to the left and hide itself while another div#2 will be sliding from the right and move to the location of of the previous slided out div.

And when the button is trigger again the div#2 will be sliding out to right while the previously hide div#1 will be sliding out from left.

I have been trying to modify the code at http://jsfiddle.net/qSvDz/ as below but I can't seem to get the result I wanted.

Could anyone pls share me some thought on how to do it.

```
function toggleDivs() {
var $home = $("#home");
var $memberHome = $("#member-home");
var $slideOut, $slideIn;

// See which <divs> should be animated in/out.
if ($home.position().left < 0) {
    $slideIn = $home;
    $slideOut = $memberHome;
}
else {
    $slideIn = $memberHome;
    $slideOut = $home;
}

$slideOut.animate({
    left: "-" + $slideOut.width() + "px"
}, function() {
    $slideIn.animate({ left: "0px" });
});
}

$("button").bind("click", function() { 
    toggleDivs();
});
```

Thanks
Fire

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/VmSX4/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="home">
            <button>Click</button>
        </div>
        <div id="member-home">
            <button>Click</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

JS/JQUERY:

```
function toggleDivs() {
    var $inner = $("#inner");

    // See which <divs> should be animated in/out.
    if ($inner.position().left == 0) {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "-400px"
        });
    }
    else {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
    }
}

$("button").bind("click", function() {
    toggleDivs();
});
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:400px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden
}
#inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px; 
}
#home {
    position:absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: red;
}

#member-home {
    position:absolute;
    left:400px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man. You save me my whole day searching for the solution. You r the man. And thx again.